# Sprite images with Gulp that doesn't require mixins or the use of specific HTML classes?

Tags: gulp, css-sprites

Im compiling my SASS with Gulp. I have a lot of background images in my SASS which I would like to sprite.

My sass looks something like this:

```
.some-class {
  background: url(images/home.png);
}

#some-id {
  background: url(images/sally.png);
}
```

Ive looked at Spritesmith and Sprity but both of these either require you to use specific classes in your HTML or mixins in your SASS.

https://github.com/Ensighten/spritesmith

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprity

I don't have full control over my HTML so I cant use icon classes like icon-fork from this method: 
https://github.com/Ensighten/grunt-spritesmith

I want to keep my SASS clean and in its current format, so I dont want to use mixins as in this method: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprity-sass

Is there not a way that I can have a task that runs over my generated CSS and converts the unsprited styles to sprited ones? I want to keep my SASS nice and clean how it currently is, I would like to modify it as little as possible.

Comment: Is it possible to use SVG assets instead? [`gulp-svgstore`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgstore) is awesome but it does require you to change your markup (svg sprites allow you to reference stuff in the sprite by doing `<svg><use xlink:href=""></use></svg>` syntax. You can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/)

Comment: Sadly no, we're still supporting IE8.

Comment: You can also try to take a look at [postcss-sprites](https://github.com/2createStudio/postcss-sprites).